# Import tensorflow contrib learn python learn

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, scikit-learn, deep-learning

I am new to tensorflow. When I am using `import tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn`   for using the DNNClassifier it is giving me an error: `module object has no attribute python` 
Python version 3.4
Tensorflow 1.7.0

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is `DNNClassifier`, then use

```
from tensorflow.contrib.learn import DNNClassifier
```

If you need the whole library, use `import tensorflow.contrib.learn`.

For completion, here are the docs for [`DNNClassifier`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/DNNClassifier) showing it is under `tensorflow.contrib.learn`. In general, you never need to include the `...python` in your tensorflow import statements.

Answer (score 0):

tensorflow.contrib.learn module does not have python module, as error message suggests. You can import DNNClassifier the following way:

```
from tensorflow.contrib.learn import DNNClassifier
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an error in your import statement. Try

`from tensorflow.contrib.learn import DNNClassifier`